# PyOpenGL glLookAt behaves weirdly after first call, with same parameters

Tags: python, opengl, camera, perspective, pyopengl

I am currently programming a small game using PyOpenGL for school (Python wasn't my choice...).

I seem to cannot wrap my head around the funcionality of the "camera". I figured that the most intuitional approach for my case is the `gluLookAt(...)` function. I want to look at my character in third person. Since my game is tile-based and logically two-dimensional, the Y-Coordinate should never change. Following is the code that I think matters (basically everything that I do with OpenGL).

This is what is called once, initially to set up OpenGL:

```
# set the perspective
fieldOfView = 45 # degrees
aspectRatio = 1800 / 1000 # given as parameters to constructor previously
gluPerspective(fieldOfView, aspectRatio, 0.1, 50.0)

# things in the back are covered by things in front of them
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
```

This is what is being called on every update:

```
# Clear Buffers
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

# render the objects in the map and ground where needed
self.renderAllObjects() # in here glBegin(..), glEnd(),
                        # glColor3fv(...) and glVertex3fv(...)
                        # are the only used OpenGL functions
# eye coords
eX = 19.5
eY = 3
eZ = 1.5

# center/lookat coords
cX = 12.5
cY = 1
cZ = 1.5

gluLookAt(eX, eY, eZ, cX, cY, cZ, 0, 1, 0)
```

When the first update is run, everything works as espected, but once I call the update function again, we are placed at some other coordinate, that seems to be in some way relative to the previous coordinate of the camera.

Online I found the functions:

- `glMatrixMode(...)` with GL_MODELVIEW and GL_PERSPECTIVE
- `glLoadIdentity()`

It was said that `glLoadIdentity()` is to be called before every `gluLookAt(...)`-call. But once I do that, I only get a black screen.

Also playing around places to put `glMatrixMode(...)` did not solve anything.

I also tried changing the order of loading objects and camera, but it seems that my current order is the right one.

Any help would be much appreciated. I am a total OpenGL newbie. Sadly after hours of research I could not wrap my head around this.

Comment: I recently had to work with OpenGL under Python. I did not manage to get what I want on screen. This was partly due to how opengl expects your matrix in terms of memory arrangement (using `numpy.asfortranarray` or `numpy.ascontiguousarray`). I posted on OpenGL forum to solve it: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/197893-View-and-Perspective-matrices. Hope it will help!

Comment: So where exactly would I fix these things in my code? I am probably overlooking something, but I read your post over and over now and did not understand it. Might be, because I am so fixed on my own code after working on this problem since last night...

Comment: I have not worked with GLU (I use the functions provided in the OpenGL forum post) so I cannot help more :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Once* before you `gluPerspective` you should:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
gluPerspective(fieldOfView, aspectRatio, 0.1, 50.0)
```

This sets the projection matrix.

Then each time you render the frame you set up the *model-view* matrix:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
gluLookAt(eX, eY, eZ, cX, cY, cZ, 0, 1, 0)
```

The projection matrix and the model-view matrix are separate state stored by the GL. So in order for `glLoadInentity` and `gluLookAt` not to override the projection matrix, you have to use `glMatrixMode` to designate which of the matrices you're currently working with.

Also you should set the model-view matrix (`gluLookAt`) *before* you render the objects (`self.renderAllObjects`).

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. I actually accidentally switched order of `self.renderAllObjects()` and `gluLookAt(...)` in my question. I had that correct.